# Query the list of CITY names from STATION that do not start with vowels and do not end with vowels

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

This is a challenge question from [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-12/problem).

My first query is working fine:

```
select distinct city
from station
where city not regexp '^[aeiou]'
and   city not regexp '[aeiou]$'
```

But my second query is giving wrong answer

```
select distinct city
from station
where city not regexp '^[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

It is compiling but giving wrong results

Comment: What does "wrong results" mean in your case? What is the actual vs the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

'NOT REGEXP' is  Negation of REGEXP,

'REGEXP' -> Checks the 'REGEXP' if satisfied then return 1 else 0

```
    select 'Chelsea' REGEXP '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$' ;

        0
```

'NOT REGEXP' -> checks the 'REGEXP' then return the opposite of the result.

```
    select 'Chelsea' not REGEXP '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$' ;

        1
```

In this case, 'Chelsea' doesn't start with vowel hence `REGEXP` is 0 and `not REGEXP` is 1.

Hence you are counting the cities, even the name starts or ends with vowels.

Comment: thanks for this clarification. so I guess the correct answer should be something like where city regexp '^[^aeiou].*[^aeiou]

Answer (score 2):

This works in MS SQL server :

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station WHERE city NOT LIKE '[AEIOU]%' AND city NOT LIKE '%[aeiou]';
```

Comment: this should be OR

Answer (score 1):

Try this it worked for me

```
select distinct city
  from station
 where city RLIKE'^[^aeiouAEIOU].*$';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM   station
WHERE  city NOT REGEXP '^[aeiouAEIOU].*|[aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

Explanation: I make sure the city does not start with ('^') vowels and also does not end with ('$') vowels.

Answer (score 1):

In Mysql,

```
where not CITY Regexp '^[aeiou].*$' or not CITY  Regexp '^.*[aeiou]$'
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using the RLIKE operator... Hope this helps:

```
select distinct CITY from STATION where CITY NOT RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU]' AND CITY NOT RLIKE '[AEIOUaeiou]$' GROUP BY CITY;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of 3 cases when using any DB

 1. Word starts with vowel but ends with consonant

 2. Word starts with consonant but ends with vowel

 3. Word starts with consonant and ends with consonant

my solution implemented in mySQL

```
select distinct(CITY) from station where CITY RLIKE '(^[^aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiou]$|^[aeiouAEIOU].*[^aeiou]$|^[^aeiouAEIOU].*[^aeiou]$)';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this MySQL Command:

`SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[^aeiou].*[^aeiou]$';`

Explanation:
DISTINCT is used to remove duplicates from the result set of a SELECT statement.
"^[^aeiou]" means city names that do not start with vowels.
"[^aeiou]$" means city names that  do not end with vowels.
".*" represents any string of any length.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

This can also work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city 
FROM station 
WHERE city NOT RLIKE  '[aeiou]$';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right answer:

```
select DISTINCT(CITY)
from STATION
Where CITY RLIKE '^[^aieouAEIOU].*[^AEIOUaeiou]$';
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
select distinct city
from station
where city rlike '^[^aeiouAEIOU].*' and city rlike '.*[^aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

Answer (score 0):

I consider both the answer right.

But some how first query is failed whereas second one is passed from hackerrank platform.

### First query

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station 
WHERE city not RLIKE '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$';
```

### Second query : `working with no issue`

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station 
WHERE city not RLIKE '^[aeiou]'
and city not rlike '[aeiou]$';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE NOT LOWER(LEFT(CITY, 1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') AND NOT LOWER(RIGHT(CITY, 1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
--This works for db2 databases
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Most of us are reading the question wrong. They want either of the one condition to be fulfilled, not the both.  The following solution works well in MS SQL Server :

```sql
select distinct city from station where (left(city,1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u') or right(city,1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u') );
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM   station
WHERE  NOT city LIKE 'A%'
       AND NOT city LIKE 'E%'
       AND NOT city LIKE 'I%'
       AND NOT city LIKE 'O%'
       AND NOT city LIKE 'U%';
```

a lengthy way but you will get the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query using a `Where column Not Rlike` clause.

This does a [pattern match of a string expression against a pattern](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-rlike-function.php).

```sql
Select Distinct city 
From station 
Where city Not Rlike '^[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU]$';
```

Additionally, the `Distinct` is used to remove all results that are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Query the list of `CITY` names from `STATION` that either do not start with vowels or do not end with vowels. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

THIS IS FOR MS SQL USERS

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE '[^aeiou]%' OR CITY LIKE '%[^aeiou]';
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the correct out put for the below code for MySql server

```sql
select distinct(city) from station 
where substr(city,1,1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u') or substr(city,-1,1) not in ('a','e','i','o','u')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest code, you can try:

```
select distinct city
from station
WHERE lower(city) Not Rlike '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$';
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT city FROM station 
WHERE lower(city) not RLIKE '^[aeiou]'
and lower(city) not rlike '[aeiou]$';
```

Comment: select distinct city
from station
WHERE lower(city) Not Rlike '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$';

Answer (score 0):

This is basic solution for this problem, I hope it will surely work.

```
Select Distinct City From Station 

Where City not LIKE 'a%a' and City not LIKE 'a%e' and City not LIKE 'a%i' and City not LIKE 'a%o' and City not LIKE 'a%u' and City not LIKE 'e%a' and City not LIKE 'e%e' and City not LIKE 'e%i' and City not LIKE 'e%o' and City not LIKE 'e%u' and City not LIKE 'i%a' and City not LIKE 'i%e'  and City not LIKE 'i%i' and City not LIKE 'i%o' and City not LIKE 'i%u' and City not LIKE 'o%a' and City not LIKE 'o%e' and City not LIKE 'o%i' and City not LIKE 'o%o' and City not LIKE 'o%u' and City not LIKE 'u%a' and City not LIKE 'u%e' and City not LIKE 'u%i' and City not LIKE 'u%o' and City not LIKE 'u%u';
```

Answer (score 0):

select distinct city as cty from station where city not in  (
select  city from Station where
Right(city,1) in  ('a','e','i','o','u') and
Left(city,1) in  ('a','e','i','o','u')
)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will be an efficiency issue. Better off left joining the select in your where clause instead.

Answer (score 0):

select DISTINCT CITY from STATION
where CITY  NOT LIKE 'a%'
AND CITY  NOT LIKE 'e%'
AND CITY  NOT LIKE 'i%'
AND CITY  NOT LIKE 'o%'
AND CITY  NOT LIKE 'u%';

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code rather than posting code only. Additional explanation will be more helpful.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34289065)

Answer (score 0):

If the `city` has a case-folding collation, then you don't need the extra letters:

```
SELECT city
    FROM station
    WHERE city REGEXP '^[^aeiou].*[^aeiou]$';
```

And what about accents on letters?  (I'm thinking of the town of Å, Norway.)

Explanations:

```
^ and $   -- anchors for start and end
[...]     -- character set
[^...]    -- inverse of character set
[^aeiou]  -- not a vowel
.*        -- zero or more characters
```

`DISTINCT` is unnecessary if you know no duplicate city names are in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and it works

```
    SELECT DISTINCT CITY
    FROM STATION
    WHERE CITY NOT REGEXP '^[aeiou]' AND CITY NOT REGEXP'[aeiou]$'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select distinct city from station where not left(city,1) in ('a','e','i','o','u');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).